# Modifying Cluster Analysis script in ArcGIS.com Incident Analysis template to add dissolve for other fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clustering, python-script-tool

I have fiddled around with some of my data, especially a high-count (> 50,000) point data set of business locations. In small scale I have successfully used ESRI's [Incident Analysis](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/11/the-incident-analysis-template-is-now-available/) to cluster these points to easily readable amounts.

All works fine, points are getting analyzed with k-means and then later displayed according to the number of counts. But unfortunately this script only adds a column with a join count and nothing more.

**I would like to be able to dissolve other fields from the point data set**, eg. employees rather than only displaying join count.

As I have far too little experience with python to change the source on my own, I hope somebody might know the trick.
[image: model builder]

The script itself comes pack in a simple toolset:

The Collect Events then does the math for the clustering:

```
"""
Tool Name:  Collect Events
Source Name: CollectEvents.py
Version: ArcGIS 10.1
Author: ESRI

This utility converts event data into weighted point data.
"""

################### Imports ########################

import os as OS
import sys as SYS
import arcpy as ARCPY
import arcpy.management as DM
import arcpy.da as DA
import ErrorUtils as ERROR
import SSUtilities as UTILS
import SSDataObject as SSDO 
import gapy as GAPY
import WeightsUtilities as WU

################ Output Field Names #################
countFieldName = "ICOUNT"

################### GUI Interface ###################

def setupCollectEvents():
"""Retrieves the parameters from the User Interface and executes the
appropriate commands."""

inputFC = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputFC = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(1)

#### Create SSDataObject ####
ssdo = SSDO.SSDataObject(inputFC, templateFC = outputFC)

countFieldNameOut, maxCount, N, numUnique = collectEvents(ssdo, outputFC)
setDerivedOutput(countFieldNameOut, maxCount)
renderResults()

def setDerivedOutput(countFieldNameOut, maxCount):
#### Set Derived Output ####
try:
    ARCPY.SetParameterAsText(2, countFieldNameOut)
    maxCount = maxCount * 1.0
    ARCPY.SetParameterAsText(3, maxCount)
except:
    ARCPY.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 902)

def renderResults():
#### Set the Default Symbology ####
params = ARCPY.gp.GetParameterInfo()
renderLayerFile = "\\templates\\layers\\CollectEventsRenderer.lyr"
templateDir = OS.path.dirname(OS.path.dirname(SYS.argv[0]))
params[1].Symbology = templateDir + renderLayerFile

def collectEvents(ssdo, outputFC):
"""This utility converts event data into weighted point data by
dissolving all coincident points into unique points with a new count
field that contains the number of original features at that
location.

INPUTS: 
inputFC (str): path to the input feature class
outputFC (str): path to the input feature class
"""

#### Set Default Progressor for Neigborhood Structure ####
ARCPY.SetProgressor("default", ARCPY.GetIDMessage(84143))

#### Validate Output Workspace ####
ERROR.checkOutputPath(outputFC)

#### True Centroid Warning For Non-Point FCs ####
if ssdo.shapeType.upper() != "POINT":
    ARCPY.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 1021)

#### Create GA Data Structure ####
gaTable, gaInfo = WU.gaTable(ssdo.inputFC, spatRef = ssdo.spatialRefString)

#### Assure Enough Observations ####
cnt = UTILS.getCount(ssdo.inputFC)
ERROR.errorNumberOfObs(cnt, minNumObs = 4)
N = gaInfo[0]
ERROR.errorNumberOfObs(N, minNumObs = 4)

#### Process Any Bad Records Encountered ####
numBadRecs = cnt - N
if numBadRecs:
    badRecs = WU.parseGAWarnings(gaTable.warnings)
    if not ssdo.silentWarnings:
        ERROR.reportBadRecords(cnt, numBadRecs, badRecs,
                               label = ssdo.oidName)

#### Create k-Nearest Neighbor Search Type ####
gaSearch = GAPY.ga_nsearch(gaTable)
gaSearch.init_nearest(0.0, 0, "euclidean")

#### Create Output Feature Class ####
outPath, outName = OS.path.split(outputFC)
try:
    DM.CreateFeatureclass(outPath, outName, "POINT", "", ssdo.mFlag, 
                          ssdo.zFlag, ssdo.spatialRefString)
except:
    ARCPY.AddIDMessage("ERROR", 210, outputFC)
    raise SystemExit()

#### Add Count Field ####
countFieldNameOut = ARCPY.ValidateFieldName(countFieldName, outPath)
UTILS.addEmptyField(outputFC, countFieldNameOut, "LONG")
fieldList = ["SHAPE@", countFieldNameOut]

#### Set Insert Cursor ####
rowsOut = DA.InsertCursor(outputFC, fieldList)

#### Set Progressor for Calculation ####
ARCPY.SetProgressor("step", ARCPY.GetIDMessage(84007), 0, N, 1)

#### ID List to Search ####
rowsIN = range(N)
maxCount = 0
numUnique = 0

for row in rowsIN:
    #### Get Row Coords ####
    rowInfo = gaTable[row]
    x0, y0 = rowInfo[1]
    count = 1

    #### Search For Exact Coord Match ####
    gaSearch.search_by_idx(row)
    for nh in gaSearch:
        count += 1
        rowsIN.remove(nh.idx)
        ARCPY.SetProgressorPosition()

    #### Keep Track of Max Count ####
    maxCount = max([count, maxCount])

    #### Create Output Point ####
    pnt = (x0, y0, ssdo.defaultZ)

    #### Create and Populate New Feature ####
    rowResult = [pnt, count]
    rowsOut.insertRow(rowResult)
    numUnique += 1
    ARCPY.SetProgressorPosition()

#### Clean Up ####
del rowsOut, gaTable

return countFieldNameOut, maxCount, N, numUnique

if __name__ == "__main__":
setupCollectEvents()
```

The result looks fine like this, where grey is the original point set and red the clustered one (with a distance set to 7,500 m in this example). The number within is the count of the points.

As the result only contains this count and no reference back to the original points, I am pretty much done with it.

What I had in mind now was to combine another dissolve function right in the model builder dialog (red box is addition like in the dissolve tool).

If that is too complicated I guess I could live with changing the python code for other point data sets too, as long as specified columns with statistic types can be dissolved. Or alternatively get an assignment list with original Feature IDs to Cluster IDs.